# MySQL Query ProgrammingError from Python Code

Tags: python, mysql

Here is the code:

```
def search():
    q2 = enttextentry.get()
    query = "SELECT Name, Year_pass_out, Gender, School_Group, Present_Institution, College_Department, Gmail_id, Phone_number, Entrance_Exams_Cleared, Password FROM registration_details where Name = '%s'"
    cursor.execute(query, (q2,)).pack()
mydb = mc.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="aishwaryakopika", database="aldb")
cursor = mydb.cursor()
```

I am getting the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If Name is a VARCHAR then most likely the problem is that you are encasing the %s in single quotes which is only for Numbers.